# How to represent the addition of the left and right tail probabilities?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

This is a very basic question, but please bear with me.

I know how to calculate the left and right tail probabilities. However, I am confused about how to represent the addition of tail probabilities in the $\Pr(\cdot)$ form.

Is the term on the left hand side the correct representation of "*adding the left and right tail probabilities*" or "*taking the sum of the left and right tail probabilities*"?
\begin{split}
\Pr \left(X<-z_c\right) + \Pr \left(X> z_c\right) = Q\left(\frac{\mu+z_c}{\sigma}\right) + Q\left(\frac{z_c-\mu}{\sigma}\right),
\end{split}
where $Q(\cdot)$ is the [$Q$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function).

Image source: [saylordotorg.github.io](https://saylordotorg.github.io/text_introductory-statistics/s09-04-areas-of-tails-of-distribution.html)

[image]

Comment: I don't know what $Q$ is, I would keep the LHS formula, it is what you are asking for.

Comment: $Q$ is the $Q$-function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function. Oh yes, the LHS. I want to confirm if the LHS is the correct representation. I will update the text.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "correct representation"?  After all, use of "+" on the left hand side looks like it expresses the intention.  What other kind of an answer would you be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the term on the left hand side the correct representation of "adding the left and right tail probabilities" or "taking the sum of the left and right tail probabilities"?

Yes --- writing $a+b$ is a valid representation of the sum of $a$ and $b$.  Consequently, what you have written is a valid representation of the sum of the tail probabilities.

The main drawback of what you have written is that you use incongruous notation for the random variable and its quantiles (which is stylistically bad, but not a formal mathematical error).  For a normal random variable $X$ it is unusual to denote the deviation from the mean by the quantile notation $z_c$.  This might potentially be confusing to some readers.

Finally, one thing that might be worth noting here is that you can express the sum of the tail probabilities in a more parsimonious form by first writing it as a single tail probability for the absolute deviation from the mean.  For all $c < \tfrac{1}{2}$ you can write:

$$\mathbb{P}(|X| > z_c) = \mathbb{P}(X<-z_c) + \mathbb{P}(X>z_c) = \cdots$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation despite the ambiguities in my texts and notations.

Answer (score 1):

In this question, $Q(z)$ is the *complementary CDF* of a standard normal random variable, that is, $Q(z) = 1-\Phi(z) = \Phi(-z)$ where $\Phi(z)$ is the CDF of a standard normal random variable. $Q(z)$ is the area under the standard normal density to the *right* of the point $z$.  Now, the figure that the OP has included uses the symbol $z_c$ (where $z_c > 0$) to denote the value of $z \in (0,\infty)$ for which $Q(z)$ equals $c$.  That is, $Q(z_c)=c$ or equivalently, $z_c = Q^{-1}(c)$.

Now, the OP writes two expressions, one of which is $$\Pr(X<-z_c)+\Pr(X>z_c)$$ He wonders whether there is an expression for this sum in terms of $\Pr(\cdot)$ that is not as unwieldy as "adding the left and right tail probabilities", and of course there is.  $\Pr(X<-z_c)+\Pr(X>z_c)$ can be expressed more succinctly as $\Pr(|X|>z_c)$, and stated in words as the probability that the absolute value of $X$ exceeds $z_c$. He does not say what kind of random variable $X$ is, but from the figure, it can be assumed that $X$ is a standard normal random variable, and thus
$$\Pr(X<-z_c)+\Pr(X>z_c)= \Pr(|X|>z_c) = 2Q(z_c) = 2c.\tag{1}$$

Bu t, the OP writes *another* expression
$$Q\left(\frac{\mu+z_c}{\sigma}\right) + Q\left(\frac{z_c-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\tag{2}$$ (which he equates to $\Pr(X<-z_c)+\Pr(X>z_c)$). This suggests that he has switched gears and now is considering $X$ to be a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. I will ignore the subscript $c$ for now and concentrate on just $z$. If $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (or $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma)$ for hard-core statisticians), then
$$\Pr(X > z) = Q\left(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$ which matches the second term in $(2)$. Also,
$$\Pr(X < -z) = \Phi\left(\frac{-z-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = Q\left(\frac{\mu+z}{\sigma}\right)$$ which matches the first term in $(2)$.

So, what's my beef with what the OP writes, namely,
$$\Pr \left(X<-z_c\right) + \Pr \left(X> z_c\right) = Q\left(\frac{\mu+z_c}{\sigma}\right) + Q\left(\frac{z_c-\mu}{\sigma}\right)??$$ Isn't that what I just proved to my own satisfaction? No, what I proved is that

$$\Pr(X < -z) + \Pr(X > z) = Q\left(\frac{\mu+z}{\sigma}\right) + Q\left(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\tag{3}$$ (notice the absence of the subscript $c$ on the $z$'s). $z_c$ has a specific meaning; it is the value of $z$ for which $Q(z)$ equals $c$. I wish to emphasize that Eq. $(3)$ holds for *all* values of $z$, not just for $z_c$, and the fact that $Q(z_c)$ equals $c$ is not needed anywhere. Neither of the two $Q(\cdots)$ in $(3)$ has value $c$ except in special cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborated explanation highlighting the ambiguity in the notations. This was very helpful information. I received multiple answers that are all very informative and I wish I could accept all of the answers. Unfortunately, I will mark @Ben's explanation as the answer as it holds the information I was looking for. Thanks once more!

Answer (score 1):

You can write your formula as $Pr[|X|>z_c]=2c$, but this formula - and your charts and expressions too - assumes a symmetric probability distribution, such as Gaussian or Student-t because $Pr[X>z_c]=Pr[X<-z_c]$. I don't see often this expression, and your formulas too, applied to asymmetric distributions, such as log-normal where generally $Pr[X>z_c]\ne Pr[X<-z_c]$.

When you deal with an asymmetric distribution then it gets complicated. There is no standard way to represent tails in such case, but many practitioners use tails with equal probabilities similar to your expressions: $2\times Pr[X>z_c]$ or for a negative value $2\times Pr[X<-z_c]$. This may seem the same as the first formula but the difference is that we're not assuming that $Pr[X>z_c]=Pr[X<-z_c]$ anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to extend this explanation for asymmetric distribution. This was very helpful information which I didn't even ask for. I received multiple answers that are all very informative and I wish I could accept all of the answers. Unfortunately, I will mark @Ben's explanation as the answer as it holds the information I was looking for. Thanks once more!

Comment: The equality $\Pr(X< -z) + \Pr(X>z) = \Pr(|X| >z)$ assumes _nothing_ about the symmetry (or lack thereof) of the density of $X$ and the two tail probabilities are very definitely not equal in value. That graph that the OP has included is very misleading because $z_c$, defined as the value of $z$ for which $Q(z)$ equals $c$ has nothing whatsoever to do with what is being calculated.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, good point, I clarified my answer. OP implicitly assumes symmetric distribution in the charts by equaling the areas under PDF for the tails with equal thresholds.

Comment: The point is that the density of $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$  _is_ symmetric, not about $0$ but about the mean point $\mu$. What is asymmetric is the placement of the intervals $(-\infty,z)$ and $(z,\infty)$ with respect to $\mu$, the point of symmetry. So, your first sentence "You can write your formula as $\Pr(|X|>z_c)=2c$" is incorrect (the $=2c$ part) because $X$ is not a standard normal random variable, it is a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variable.  The OP correctly calculates $\Pr(|X|>z_c)$ in terms of $Q(\cdot)$; what is sought is a succinct description of LHS which is $\Pr(|X|>z_c)$ in words.